# Change url with port in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to change a url http://example.com:88/test/ to https://example.com/test, using nginx. I tried using rewrite in the port 88 block but that didn't work.

At the moment i use.

```
    server {
       listen 88;
       server_name example.com
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
```

Currently http://example.com:88/test/ is sent to https://example.com:88/test/

Comment: From [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host)
**$host**
`in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the “Host” request header field, or the server name matching a request`

Answer (score 0):

That looks ok, "$host" does not include the port... or shouldn't.

whats the ouptut using "curl" or "httpie"?

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/88_port
server {
        listen 88;
        server_name localhost;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
$ http localhost:88/xpto
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 194
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 12:32:21 GMT
Location: https://localhost/xpto
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

This seems to be working just fine in 1.10, so unless there's another redirect that should work.